# Creating a 4 partitions Linux/Windows USB drive

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, persistence, tails-os

I want to create a single 16GB usb drive with the following:

- (A) 4GB FAT32 Partition usable in Windows (not installing Windows at all, just shared space)
- (B) 4GB Linux live distro
- (C) 4GB ext3 Encrypted Persistence
- (D) 4GB TAILS live

I have researched a lot and tried 5 times to do it but always encounter some trouble.

I have seen some "multiboot" tools that copy ISOs and boots from there, that will be fine for Tails, but I think not for the other parts? (YUMI, XBOOT, Easy2boot, etc)

Take in mind that I want to use persistence.

> *On my last attempt I have done this:*
>
> Created the **(B)** partition leaving 4gb space at the beginning of
>   the USB drive and installed the Linux distro via Universal USB
>   Installer on Windows, this because for what I seen Windows only sees
>   the first partition, so later I can create the FAT32 Partition usable
>   in Windows **(A)**
>
> Created the other partitions on their respective places (A, C, D).
>
> (After this I can't see the A partition on windows, but I can see it and use it on Linux, it's on the beginning of the drive)
>
> Tried to install Tails on the **(D)** partition, without success

The thing is now I can't see the first partition on Windows nor install TAILS on the (D) partition without getting a "boot error" at startup when I tried to install grub from inside the Linux distro.

Is it possible that someome can give me orientation on how to do this the right way? Even if its not a step by step, just tell me what are the correct steps and I can research them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not supported to have other partitions than the two tails uses on the media.

You could try, but don't be surprised if a removal or creation of your persistent partition wipes other partitions.